# How does padding + line-height overwrite height?

Tags: css, height

in this example

```
https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/1ea1ef35d942d0041b0467b4d39888d3
```

When I played with `padding` in `.flex-item` css, I found it can overwrite `height` limit that is `padding + line-height > height`, where can I find such precedence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total height of the element includes padding. 
You can add

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

for `.flex-item`

`border-box` tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height. If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any border or padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb that extra width. This typically makes it much easier to size elements.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing. for more details.

Answer (score 0):

That's a normal behavior.

Your flex-item has a huge line-height. If you add padding to it, then your content extends the size of your container (your div). You have to stay coherent between the height you want, and the line-height/padding you add to it.

Comment: Sorry pal but the other one is more specific, thanks for your time!